# Angularjs - Accessing javascript object in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, scope

I have a simple custom directive on which one of the attributes is a javascript object.  I have tried multiple ways to access the object from the controller with no luck.

Custom directive in index.html

```
 <schedule person = "person" day="july25">July 25</schedule>
```

Directive partial (schedulepartial.html):

```
<a href="#" ng-click=scheduledirctrl.calltoggle() ng-class={{scheduledirctrl.setClass}}>July 25</a>
```

Directive Module:

```
angular.module('scheduleDirective', [])

.directive('schedule', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      iperson: '=person',
          day: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: 'schedulepartial.html',

    link: function(scope, element, attributes){

        console.log("link person name "+scope.iperson.name);
        scope.person = scope.iperson;
    },

    controller: function($scope, $element,$attrs,$http){

            $scope.day = $attrs.day
            this.calltoggle = function() {
                this.toggle($scope.person, $scope.day);
            }

            this.setClass = "{'active' : person." + $attrs.day + ", 'btn-primary' : person." + $attrs.day + " }";

        this.toggle = function(person,day){         
              console.log("toggle" + person.name + day);
    },
    controllerAs: 'scheduledirctrl'
  };
});
```

Within the `link` function I have access to the object verified in the log.  Based on other answers to similar questions, I tried saving the object in a new property in the scope.

However, in the `controller`, when I access either `$scope.person` or `$scope.iperson` to send them to the `toggle()` function, I get an `undefined` error.

Oddly, the `ng-class` expression received from `this.setClass` works perfectly and it is accessing `person`.

Comment: Ran your code, it was missing a '}' (your missing one for the 'this.toggle' function).
It seems to run fine for me after that, so check it out and give and update